# JVM freezes when AttributedString's iterator is drawn by graphics object

Tags: java, arrays, nsattributedstring, graphics2d, freeze

I have an array of AttributedString objects. I use them so that I can set part of the string one color and the rest of the string another color.

I have noticed, however, that everything stalls in the code when the graphics object uses the drawString() method on the AttributedString.getIterator(). The code stops right on the first one and then continues normally for the rest.

I also have reason to believe that the getIterator() method is not what is slowing it down. I have tried making an array of AttributedCharacterIterators that gets the iterators from the AttributedString array while the other resources are loading and using that array for the drawing of the strings.

If it helps, I am on Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 Also, the installed JRE I'm using is Java SE 8 [1.8.0_65].

Here is the relevant code:

```
private static AttributedString[] exampleList = new AttributedString[6];

// In the main method
exampleList[0] = new AttributedString("Example String Zero");
exampleList[0].addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE, 0, 2);
exampleList[1] = new AttributedString("Example String One");
exampleList[1].addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE, 0, 5);
exampleList[2] = new AttributedString("Example String Two");
exampleList[2].addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE, 0, 3);
exampleList[3] = new AttributedString("Example String Three");
exampleList[3].addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE, 0, 4);
exampleList[4] = new AttributedString("Example String Four");
exampleList[4].addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE, 0, 5);
exampleList[5] = new AttributedString("Example String Five");
exampleList[5].addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.BLUE, 0, 2);
for(int i = 0; i < creditNames.length; ++i)
    exampleList[i].addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, scoreFont);

// In the paintComponent(Graphics g) method overriden for the JPanel where everything is drawn
g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2d.setFont(scoreFont);
int y = 10;
for(AttributedString a : exampleList)
    g2d.drawString(a.getIterator(), 50, y += 50);
```

If anything else is needed, please let me know.